# JS radial-progress-bar redirect after the count finishing

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

I using this:radial-progress-bar to countdown 9 minuts
 link: http://hellodesign.com.br/site/sometests/js/radial-progress-bar.js

and made a div with id="time_session"

-JS-

```
$("#time_session").radialProgress("init", {'size': 45, 'fill': 5})
                  .radialProgress("to", {'perc': 100, 'time': 90000});
```

I need to add ajax code telling that after the count finish redirect to other page. how to do that ? thanks.

Comment: Add setTimeout function with duration as 90000 and in that keep the ajax call.

Comment: everytime the page will refresh the count will reset. so i need to teel when the count finish 90000 redirect.

Comment: the radialprogress will anyways reset on each page refresh and so will the setTimeout function. Why do you need ajax call to redirect to the other page?

Comment: I working with codeigniter and want to destroy the session if no user using the page until the count finish.